# ORA 12154 Could not resolve the connect identifier Specified

Tags: oracle

I am using Mobile Terminal which is connected to database.

I am able to successfully log in to the database with my Mobile Terminal. But while scanning the barcode, I am getting ORA-12154 issue.

I have checked all the configuration files related to this issue, everything looks good.

Not sure why I am getting this issue while using some functionality in between but while I am successfully able to connect to the database.

What log files or configuration files do I need to check?.

**EDIT:**

**tnsnames.ora**

`DEV = (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = DEVMC)(PORT = 1521)) ) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = DEV) ) )`

**sqlnet.ora :**

```
SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NTS) NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (TNSNAMES, EZCONNECT)
```

**listener.ora**

```
 LISTENER = (DESCRIPTION_LIST = (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = DEVMC)(PORT = 1521)) 
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521)) ) )
```

and I have all these files under `TNSADMIN` directory

Comment: please share how the connection to the database is made, that's probably what is wrong here

Comment: Are you sure that you are really connected to database? Usually such error appear while logon procedure.